# Javascript animation and 360 degree image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I have been trying to figure out how to make something similar to this solution here: [Sample](http://www.aarsleff.dk/aarsleff-world)

I have been doing some research, and have stumbled upon some pretty lightweight jQuery plugins that can make the 360 degree image rotation. What i can't figure out:

- How to make similar menu points, so that they are clickable but still rotating with the image?
- Would you guys use HTML5 or JS to create that starting animation, where the image components fall down and gets gathered to one image?

Now, i dont expect a "solution" for this, just some suggestions and ideas, so i can approach this the smartest way possible.

Comment: It depends on how those "lightweight jQuery plugins" accomplish that. So I assume they are working with moving x and y coordinates. So when their value changes you need to make those menu points change their position accordingly.

Comment: Look at its source it is done using images for every degree

Comment: Yeah i see that they are using ~200 images,. The rotating part is not that difficult one here. 

@treegarden Yeah i get what your going for, and thats probably what they are doing. Do you have any theory about, why they are including the menu points in the actual images?

Comment: The part you're missing is that you can't accomplish that without having a 3D representation. It looks like they built a 3D model, and rendered out {however many} images from a camera orbit. X_X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that was a mixture of HTML5 and JS, probably using a plugin like GSAP http://greensock.com/draggable (there's a nice draggable spinner example on this page) but there's also http://julian.com/research/velocity/

As others have said in the comments this could have been initially built with a 3D modeller, maybe Blender http://www.blender.org/features/ in which case this is a mixture of HTML5 canvas elements for the buttons and WebGL

**update**

If you want a 3D model animation the best plugin to use with WebGL is http://threejs.org/ which I'd forgotten about

These tutorials may help too

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1253
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000802/ch04.html
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_transforms/

Comment: I think i spotted a library in the source code called YUI. It's apparently Yahoo's UI library. Never heard of it, and i dont know if the site relies entirely off of it

Comment: ah right, never heard of YUI before, just found this tutorial on it though http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-yui--net-16746 and it looks like it has an animation module http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/anim/ so that's most likely how this was created. YUI is no longer actively maintained by Yahoo so it may not be the best option for you, I'd recommend canvas and WebGL

Comment: I actually ended up using jQuery all the way for this one. Greensock for the first animation, and then Threesixty.js for the rotation/dragging part. I ofcourse had to expand a lot on functionality to make it work, but i'd still say it's a pretty lightweight solution. At least it runs better than the link i referred to :)

Comment: cool, I know jQuery is easy to use but it's actually not very efficient when it comes to animation. It takes a lot longer than pure JS. That's why velocity.js is so awesome, it let's you use jQuery but you replace every .animate with .velocity and you get a similar speed to JS animations. Havem't used threesixty.js before I'll check it out